# Get the _id of the last upserted document in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to find the _id of the last upserted document in java. I am using 2.0.5. I do not see an 'upserted' field in the output returned by getLastError if the element was updated. I do see it if the element was inserted. I need to get the _id regardless of whether the element was updated or inserted. Is it possible to get the _id of the document in some way other than issuing another find command? I am trying to reduce the unnecessary query.

Comment: I think you have to use another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DBCollection.findAndModify(). You can set it's parameters such that it will perform the upsert and return a DBObject containing the _id of the object you just created/modified.

Check out the docs for a lot more info:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

ADDENDUM: I just revisited my answer and realize that there's a better, easier way. The value of _id is always set client-side, before the document is sent over the wire to the server. The driver does this for you, if you haven't assigned a value to the _id already. Since the client sets the _id, you know what it is even before the insert operation start. consider this example.

```
> var id = ObjectId()
> id
ObjectId("5511062d729ddce46b99ea3f")
> db.test.insert( { _id: id, text:"a trivial experiment"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find( { _id: id} )
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5511062d729ddce46b99ea3f"),
    "text" : "a trivial experiment"
}
```

Comment: I believe @Asha want to use the upserted feature so he can minimize the amount of query needed.

Comment: FindAndUpdate will perform the upsert and return the target document in single call to the server

Comment: I tried it out, it works great. It returns the new or old document depending on the parameters passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code Will Give You last Modified record:

```
db.products.find().sort({"$natural":1}).limit(1);
```

Following Codes Will Give You last Inserted record:

```
db.products.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1);
db.products.find().sort({"$natural":-1}).limit(1);
```